# CakePHP 2.1 - Unit Testing Controllers $this->view and $this->contents equals null

Tags: cakephp, phpunit, cakephp-2.1

Swtiching a over to cakephp 2.1 and just starting to learn unit testing...

When I `ArticlesControllerTestCase::testView()`

and run

```
$this->testAction('articles/view/1'); 
debug($this->view); 
debug($this->contents); 
die;
```

both `$this->view and $this->contents` is equal to null

I've emptied the beforeFilter calls and beforeRender calls to try and elimitate that...

I noticed that in the controller action, if I set `$this->render('view');` at the end of the method I get `$this->view` = 'what it is suppose to be', but `$this->contents` = 'to the same thing and does not contain the layout

any idea why this would be happening?

```
class ArticlesController extends MastersController {

    /*
     * Name
     */
    public $name = 'Articles';

    /*
     * Publicly Accessible Methods
     */
    public $allowed = array('view', 'index', 'category', 'news');


    /*
     * Default Search Params
     */
    public $presetVars = array(
        array('field' => 'title', 'type' => 'value'),
        array('field' => 'category_id', 'type' => 'value'),
        array('field' => 'status_id', 'type' => 'value'),           
    );

    /*
     * Admin Menu Options
     */
    public $adminMenu = array('index'=>array('Category'));

    /**
     * Before Filter Callback
     * (non-PHPdoc)
     * @see controllers/MastersController::beforeFilter()
     * @return void
     */
    public function beforeFilter(){
        parent::beforeFilter();
        $categories = $this->Article->Category->find('class', array('article', 'conditions'=>array('not'=>array('Category.name'=>'Content'))));
        $this->set(compact('categories'));
    }

    /**
     * View
     * @param $id
     * @see controllers/MastersController::_view()
     * @return void
     */
    public function view($id){
        parent::_view($id);
        $articleTitle = $this->Article->findField($id,'title');
        $recentNews = $this->Article->find('recentNews');
        $this->set('title_for_layout', $articleTitle);
        $this->set(compact('recentNews'));
    }
};

class MastersController extends AppController {

    /*
     * Name
     */
    public $name = 'Masters'; # expected to be overridden

    /**
     * View
     * Default view method for all controllers
     * Provides an individual record based on the record id
     * @param int $id: model id
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _view($id){
        $this->Redirect->idEmpty($id, array('action'=>'index'));
        ${Inflector::singularize($this->request->params['controller'])} = $this->{$this->modelClass}->find('record', array($id));
        ${Inflector::variable(Inflector::singularize($this->request->params['controller']))} = ${Inflector::singularize($this->request->params['controller'])};

        if(empty(${Inflector::singularize($this->request->params['controller'])})){
            return $this->Redirect->flashWarning('Invalid Id.', $this->referer());
        }       
        $this->set(compact(Inflector::singularize($this->request->params['controller']), Inflector::variable(Inflector::singularize($this->request->params['controller']))));
    }
}


class ArticlesControllerTestCase extends ControllerTestCase {

    /**
     * Fixtures
     *
     * @var array
     */
    public $fixtures = array('app.article');

    /**
     * Set Up
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function setUp() {
        parent::setUp();
        $this->Articles = new TestArticlesController();
        $this->Articles->constructClasses();
    }

    /**
     * Tear Down
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function tearDown() {
        unset($this->Articles);

        parent::tearDown();
    }

    /**
     * Test View
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function testView() {
        $this->testAction('articles/view/1');
        debug($this->view); die;
    }
}


class ArticleFixture extends CakeTestFixture {

    /**
     * Fields
     *
     * @var array
     */
    public $fields = array(
        'id' => array('type' => 'integer', 'null' => false, 'default' => NULL, 'key' => 'primary'),
        'slug' => array('type' => 'string', 'null' => true, 'default' => NULL, 'length' => 120, 'collate' => 'latin1_swedish_ci', 'charset' => 'latin1'),
        'title' => array('type' => 'string', 'null' => false, 'default' => NULL, 'length' => 100, 'collate' => 'latin1_swedish_ci', 'charset' => 'latin1'),
        'body' => array('type' => 'text', 'null' => false, 'default' => NULL, 'collate' => 'latin1_swedish_ci', 'charset' => 'latin1'),
        'created' => array('type' => 'datetime', 'null' => false, 'default' => NULL),
        'modified' => array('type' => 'datetime', 'null' => false, 'default' => NULL),
        'status_id' => array('type' => 'integer', 'null' => false, 'default' => NULL),
        'category_id' => array('type' => 'integer', 'null' => false, 'default' => NULL),
        'indexes' => array('PRIMARY' => array('column' => 'id', 'unique' => 1)),
        'tableParameters' => array('charset' => 'utf8', 'collate' => 'utf8_general_ci', 'engine' => 'InnoDB')
    );

    /**
     * Records
     *
     * @var array
     */
    public $records = array(
        array(
            'id' => '1',
            'slug' => NULL,
            'title' => 'Test Article #1 without slug - published',
            'body' => '<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p><p>Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>',
            'created' => '2011-02-15 21:14:03',
            'modified' => '2011-02-15 21:14:03',
            'status_id' => '1',
            'category_id' => '5'
        ),
         );
}
```

Comment: `$this` does not refer to your controller, but to your test case.

Answer (score 1):

This can happen if you're being redirected, for example, by some auth code that redirects to a login page if session data isn't as expected.  If you haven't set up the required environment in your tests, you'll get redirected.  You can check this by checking the value of `$this->headers`:

```
debug("Headers: " . print_r($this->headers));
```

If you put that in your test and see something like `array('Location' => 'your_login_page')`, make sure your test environment includes everything necessary to keep your auth system (or anything else that may be inserting redirects) happy.

Answer (score 0):

You need to capture the result of $this->testAction and specify what you want to return ( http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/testing.html#testing-controllers )

e.g.

```
$result = $this->testAction('articles/view/1', array('return'=>'content'));

debug($result);
```

Comment: I encountered this problem. Supplying the "return" will still result to nulls unless the articles/view/1 accepts a post request. the method=get option must be provided in the testAction()

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning to perform unit testing, you should really look at testing each individual unit.  This being said, PHPUnit, when integrated into CakePHP is reasonably robust and can provide things you need like data and method mocking.

When I write a unit test it looks a little like this:

```
function testSomeTestCaseWithDescriptiveMethodName(){
    $this->testAction("controller/action/arguments");
    $this->assertEqual([some value or data set], $this->vars["key"];
}
```

This will let you test against the values created without doing an integration test which would include views, database access, etc.

I hope this helps. : )

Answer (score -1):

I think I know what causes the problem. You need to supply the method for the testAction().

```
$this->testAction('articles/view/1', array('method'=>'get')); 
debug($this->view); //should output the view
debug($this->contents);  //should output the contents
```

IMHO, the docs (http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/testing.html#testing-controllers) make it look like that the default is GET. The default is actually POST - so "posting" to articles/view/1 would get you nothing.

Comment: also try to debug($this->headers) - to check if you were redirected from the page

Comment: still set as null...  if I set $this->render('view'); in the controller action, then $this->view/$this->contents are set correctly. However I should not need to do this.. and debug($this->headers) is still an empty array.  I have got to figure this out soon, running behind on this project.

Comment: $this->headers will be empty if you were not redirected. If you have the $this->view / $this->contents then you should just do the assertions on those IMHO....

I am new to CakePHP - if you have more questions then #cakephp in freenode is also a great way to ask people...